# How Do I Replace/Change The Heading Text Inside <h3></h3>, Using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I change/replace the `<h3>` text: "Featured Offers" using javascript to say "Public Offers" instead?

```
</div>  <!-- FEATURED OFFERS -->
<div class="panel">
   <div class="head">
      <h3>Featured Offers</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="body">
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
```

Comment: I have no access to the HTML code, BTW.

Comment: And there are other <h3> tags within the document. How do I just switch <h3>Featured Offers</h3> and not the other H3 tags?

Comment: and are those `<h3>` tags inside others `<div class="head">` ?

Answer (score 47):

If you can select it, you can manipulate it.

Try this:

```
$(".head h3").html("your new header");
```

But as others mentioned, you probably want `head` div to have an id.

Comment: I had to put `$("h3.head").html("your new header");` for it to work.  But thanks!

Comment: @daneiswork: because in your markup it's the `h3` that has class `head`. The markup in the question is different.

Comment: Ahhhhh okay.  That makes sense.  Thanks for saying so.

Answer (score 41):

you don't - not like this.
give an id to your  tag , lets say it looks like this now :

```
<h3 id="myHeader"></h3>
```

then set the value like that :

```
myHeader.innerText = "public offers";
```

Comment: Mmmh i believe you do. And jQuery makes it a little bit easier than pure Javascript.

Comment: general speaking you are right- but in my opinion not in this particular case - it is allways important to give tags , if not to the <h3> atleast for the <head> so there won't be any bugs ahead. anyway if you don't have an access i guess you can use talnicolas advice. nice day for you friends..

Comment: This is really the only answer that resolves the issue without potentially creating more. If you use the others you are just going to arbitrarily change the other headers that the person could decide to add later.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Among all the others. Thanks: @barak ben horin

Comment: I have multiple h3 so this seems the best solution, but I use .text('some value') rather than innerText.

Comment: Is it jquery syntax? Never seen an `id` as `object`. Does it work?

Answer (score 28):

```js
$("h3").text("context")
```

Just use method "text()".

> The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or
>   get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val()
>   method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Note that this will set the text contents of each `<h3>` element if there's more than one.

Answer (score 17):

Give an id to h3 like this:

```
<h3 id="headertag">Featured Offers</h3>
```

and in the javascript function do this :

```
document.getElementById("headertag").innerHTML = "Public Offers";
```

Answer (score 13):

try this,

```
$(".head h3").html("New header");
```

or

```
$(".head h3").text("New header");
```

***remember class selectors returns all the matching elements.***

Answer (score 10):

Something like:

```
$(".head h3").html("Public offers");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".head h3").html('Public Offers');
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: I think there are no need to explain bacause its a basic javascript concept.

Comment: Morning @DeepakkumarSaini, remember that even a basic can improve our knowledge

Comment: Not one, not two, but three answers with this solution were already posted here. 7 years ago. There's really no need for another one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var headingDiv       = document.getElementById("head");
headingDiv.innerHTML = "<H3>Public Offers</H3>";
```

Comment: `head` div doesn't have an `id` in the example. So this a) won't work, b) is simply wrong solution.

Comment: ohhhooo...ur right. I didn't see it quite right. head is a class. Then it would be better, to assign an id to either H3 or to div containing it and do this. what do you say ?

Comment: I personally would assign an ID, but your solution is wrong anyway. It overwrites entire content of head div.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **JQuery**, you could use the following snippet

```
onSomethingChange() {
  $("#your_element_id").text("the text you want to be appeared")
}
```

This is if you change your HTML element depending on some **event**,
and the string inside text method could be replaced with another element value like the following snippet

```
onSomethingChange() {
  $("#your_element_id").text($("#your_other_element_id").val())
}
```

But remember this works when you put **id** to your HTML elements, **that will not be used as field like inputs**

Answer (score -1):

Hope that help someone:-

Element with a class attribute with the value of "className":

```
<h3 class="className"></h3>
```

You will make a refernce of by the class name:

```
const newTitle = document.querySelector(".className");
```

Then change the content:

```
newTitle.textContent = "New Title";
```