# How do I change a div's text content on button click? Vanilla JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript

```
 <div class="placeholder">
   <h3>Select</h3>
 </div>

 <div class="buttons">
   <button data-filter="*">Show all</button>
   <button data-filter=".stadia">Stadia</button>
   <button data-filter=".leisure">Leisure</button>
   <button data-filter=".heritage">Listed Heritage</button>
   <button data-filter=".residential">Residential</button>
   <button data-filter=".retail">Retail</button>
   <button data-filter=".healthcare">Healthcare</button>
   <button data-filter=".commercial">Commercial</button>
   <button data-filter=".facilities">Facilities Management</button>
   <button data-filter=".education">Education</button>
 </div>
```

Hello!

I would like the text in .placeholder h3 ("select") to change to the text in the selected button on click "show all" etc

I'm not overly familiar with Javascript so I don't even know where to start. I know it would be easier with an input field but this is tied into another function which I honestly don't have the ability to change.

**EDIT: Eugenes answer resolved the issue, with all me having to do in the HTML is add a 'text-output' class to the h3. Thanks again!**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8550251/438992, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898475/using-jquery-to-replace-text-inside-h3-header/12898625, etc. for the text replacement, how to do something on a click is equally searchable.

Comment: *"I'm not overly familiar with Javascript so I don't even know where to start."* - A great place to start is a Google search for things like "JavaScript tutorial" or, if you want to use jQuery as indicated in the title, "jQuery tutorial".  There are many resources available to you.  Stack Overflow does not seek to replace tutorials or provide tutoring services.  Once you get started, if you encounter a problem such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.

Comment: No worries thanks, I usually google and the first thing to come up is Stack Overflow, I don't particularly use JS that much, but I think that's because I avoid it! I'll find some tuts online! Do I need to close this Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/qt7cpaxd/

JS

```
buttonArray = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (let i = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++) {

  buttonArray[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('.text-output').innerText = e.target.innerText;

  })

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="placeholder">
  <h3 class="text-output">Select</h3>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button data-filter="*">Show all</button>
  <button data-filter=".stadia">Stadia</button>
  <button data-filter=".leisure">Leisure</button>
  <button data-filter=".heritage">Listed Heritage</button>
  <button data-filter=".residential">Residential</button>
  <button data-filter=".retail">Retail</button>
  <button data-filter=".healthcare">Healthcare</button>
  <button data-filter=".commercial">Commercial</button>
  <button data-filter=".facilities">Facilities Management</button>
  <button data-filter=".education">Education</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @John-LukeWard now for homework I advise you to target only the buttons inside the div class buttons otherwise you'll target all buttons and you don't want that.

Comment: Thanks i'll give that a go!

Comment: Hi @EugeneSunic, I added a class to the query selector:
        buttonArray = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons button');

Comment: @John-LukeWard good stuff, would be also good to put an id instead of a class for the h3 html element...

Answer (score 0):

Not in this lazy way ;) You need to give the div a ID

```
      <div id="ibims" class="buttons">

     function change_ibims(id, src)
         var ibims=document.getElementById(id);
         if (ibims){ // check if the element is inside the dom
            ibims.innerHTML=src;
         } 
      }
```

now you can find and change this div by something like

```
     var id="ibims";
     var src="wahtever you want";
     change_ibims(id, src);
```

or

```
     <input type="button" caption="clickme" 
     onclick="javascript:change_ibims('ibims','Hello Hello')">
```