# Passing data to a bootstrap h3 element in modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog

I've this html code

```
<button class="btn btn-warning slider__button--primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-name="product name">more...</button>
```

When I click on this button, I want to open a bootstrap 4 modal, and pass this Name  to 'h3' tag in the modal.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="subscribe" class="btn btn-warning mx-3 my-sm-2 ml-sm-0 ml-md-0 px-md-3" value="products/details">subscribe now</button>
                                                        
</div>
```

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var name = button.data('name')
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-body h3').val(name)
})
```

How can I pass data to h3 element??

Comment: Use `.html(name)` instead of `.val(name)`. `val()` is used for form input fields.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I Replace/Change The Heading Text Inside <h3></h3>, Using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550251/how-do-i-replace-change-the-heading-text-inside-h3-h3-using-jquery)

Comment: Ooobs, Thanks a lot, working for me